# get string after getline()

Tags: c++, getline

I want to hold a string with spaces therefore I used `getline()` but after it I want to get another string(no spaces) if there is a `-e` for example  and the string after it in `s2`, but since in my code I lose the dash when using `getline()` I can't seem to achieve what I'm trying to do. any suggestions would be really helpful.

```
//example input: -f name -b blah blah -e email
//looking for output:
//name 
//blah blah
//email


string s,s1,s2;
char check_character;

while (cin.peek() != '\n')
{
    if (cin.get() == '-')
    {
        check_character = cin.get();
        switch(check_character)
        {
            case 'f':
            cin >> s;
            break;
            case 'b':
            if(cin.peek() != '\n')
                getline(cin, s1, '-');
            else if(cin.peek() =='\n')
                getline(cin, s1);
            break;
            case 'e':
            cin>> s2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << s << endl << s1 << endl << s2 << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `getline` and then parse the output.

Comment: It seems you are parsing command-line arguments. If you do, first of all consider using a library for that, like [Boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/program_options.html), or "standard" function like [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) on POSIX systems. And no matter what you use, a library or your own implementation, consider to make the multi-word argument a *single* argument by using quotes when invoking your program. For example `-b "blaha blaha"`. The shell will treat `"blaha blaha"` as a *single* argument to your program.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to do a single call to `getline()` then parse the "command" string. There are many options of achieving this, from a simple `split()` on "-" or `find('-')`

Comment: `a simple split()` Would you mind to explain which `split()` do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

`getline()` extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found or the newline character, `'\n'`.

**If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded (i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it).**

Answer (score 0):

The way you parse the arguments could certainly be improved, but this answer is not about it. I think what you are looking for is to simply put the `-` char back into the stream after `std::getline` removed it. In this case you could just use `.putback()` method

```
if (std::cin.peek() != '\n')
{
    std::getline(std::cin, s1, '-');
    std::cin.putback('-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a couple assumptions here:

1. You never expect a '\n' except at the end of the input string, even after "-b" (which your code will currently read in)
2. You expect to only accept 1 of each type of argument (cause your current code will stomp any previous entries)

A [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) will handle this nicely with the `regex`:

```
(?:\s*-f\s+(\w+)|\s*-b\s+([^-]+)|\s*-e\s+(\w+))*
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/cfX5AJ/1)

You'll need to start by reading from `cin` into a variable, for example `string input`. This could be done like:

```
getline(cin, input)
```

Once you have your input you can simply do:

```
if(smatch m; regex_search(input, m, regex{ "(?:\\s*-f\\s+(\\w+)|\\s*-b\\s+([^-]+)|\\s*-e\\s+(\\w+))*" })) {
    if(m[1].length() > 0U) {
        cout << "-f " << m[1] << endl;
    }

    if(m[2].length() > 0U) {
        cout << "-b " << m[2] << endl;
    }

    if(m[3].length() > 0U) {
        cout << "-e " << m[3] << endl;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/aHJYxC)

Answer (score 0):

If you go the approach of reading in the entire line, and you do not want to use Boost program options, or getopts, you could parse the line yourself (as has been suggested).  Here would be one way of doing it, as an alternative of parsing on the fly in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::get;
using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;
using std::make_tuple;
using std::string;
using std::tuple;
using std::vector;

static auto chunkLine(string const& line)
{
  auto result = vector<string>{};
  auto i = string::size_type{};
  while (i != string::npos && i < line.size())
  {
    auto pos = line.find(" -", i);
    auto count = pos == string::npos ? pos : (pos - i);
    result.push_back(line.substr(i, count));
    i = pos + (pos != string::npos ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return result;
}

static auto parseChunks(vector<string> const& chunks)
{
  auto result = vector<tuple<string, string>>{};
  for (auto const& chunk : chunks)
  {
    auto pos = chunk.find(" ");
    if (pos != string::npos && chunk[0] == '-')
    {
      auto kv = make_tuple(chunk.substr(1, pos-1), chunk.substr(pos+1));
      result.push_back(kv);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  auto line = "-f name -b blah blah -e email"s;
  auto keyValueTuples = parseChunks(chunkLine(line));
  for (auto const& kv : keyValueTuples)
  {
    cout << get<1>(kv) << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put cin.ignore before typing getline as in your code:

```
`string s,s1,s2;
char check_character;

while (cin.peek() != '\n')
 {
    if (cin.get() == '-')
 {
    check_character = cin.get();
    switch(check_character)
    {
        case 'f':
        cin >> s;
        break;
        case 'b':
        if(cin.peek() != '\n')
            cin.ignore
            getline(cin, s1, '-');
        else if(cin.peek() =='\n')
            cin.ignore
            getline(cin, s1);
        break;
        case 'e':
        cin>> s2;
        break;
    }
}
}
cout << s << endl << s1 << endl << s2 << endl;
return 0; `
```